Receive i2S data to RP2040, PIO and DMA from MEMS microphone (SPH0645LM4H-B)
It pretty much seem to work. I have in the PIO been able to generate the clock and word select and the microphone is sending data continuously which can be verified with a logic analyser.

(maybe it takes time for the image being processed, meanwhile here is a dropbox link to the same image: link)
Here is my PIO program:
;i2s generate square wave on pin 2, 1.4 Mhz, frame sync on pin 3, 28 kHz
;input on pin 1
.program blink
.wrap_target
;[18] not [19] since push in the end takes one
    set pins, 0   [18]
    set x, 23     [1]
    set pins, 2   [20]
lp1:
    set pins, 0   [20]
    set pins, 2   [19]
    jmp x-- lp1   [1]

    set pins, 4   [9]
    set x, 22     [1]
    in pins, 1    [10]
    set pins, 6   [20]
lp2:
    set pins, 4   [10]
    in pins, 1    [10]
    set pins, 6   [19]
    jmp x-- lp2   [1]
    push          [1]
.wrap

So in lp2 loop and righ before the loop I run in on pin 1 which is the data pin from the microphone. My understanding is that this adds bits to a register, after the lp2 loop I push and my understanding is that I send everything in the shift register to the main cpu.
In main CPU I have this code running:
#include "source.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

#include "hardware/pio.h"
#include "hardware/clocks.h"
#include "hardware/dma.h"
#include "hardware/irq.h"

#include "pico/audio.h"
#include "pico/audio_i2s.h"

#include "pico/binary_info.h"

#include "toggle_pin.pio.h"

uint32_t bufferA[256];
uint32_t bufferB[256];
volatile uint32_t* activeBuffer = bufferA;
volatile uint32_t* processingBuffer = bufferB;
volatile bool bufferReady = false;

int dma_chan;

void dma_irq_handler() {
    // Check if the transfer is complete
    if (dma_hw->ints0 & (1u << dma_chan)) {
        // Clear the interrupt request
        dma_hw->ints0 = 1u << dma_chan;

        // Swap buffers
        volatile uint32_t* temp = processingBuffer;
        processingBuffer = activeBuffer;
        activeBuffer = temp;

        // Mark buffer as ready for processing
        bufferReady = true;

        dma_channel_set_write_addr(dma_chan, activeBuffer, true);

        dma_channel_start(dma_chan);
    }
}

void setup_dma(PIO pio, uint sm) {
    // Allocate a DMA channel
    dma_chan = dma_claim_unused_channel(true);

    // Configure the DMA channel to read from PIO RX FIFO and write to `buffer`
    dma_channel_config c = dma_channel_get_default_config(dma_chan);
    channel_config_set_transfer_data_size(&c, DMA_SIZE_32);
    channel_config_set_read_increment(&c, false); // PIO FIFO address doesn't increment
    channel_config_set_write_increment(&c, true); // Increment buffer address
    channel_config_set_dreq(&c, pio_get_dreq(pio, sm, false)); // Set DREQ for PIO RX

    // Enable chain-to-self for continuous transfer
    //channel_config_set_chain_to(&c, dma_chan);

    dma_channel_configure(
        dma_chan,
        &c,
        activeBuffer, // Destination pointer
        &pio->rxf[sm], // Source pointer (PIO RX FIFO)
        sizeof(activeBuffer) / sizeof(activeBuffer[0]), // Number of transfers
        true // Start immediately
    );

    // Configure the DMA interrupt
    dma_channel_set_irq0_enabled(dma_chan, true);
    irq_set_exclusive_handler(DMA_IRQ_0, dma_irq_handler);
    irq_set_enabled(DMA_IRQ_0, true);
}


int main() {
    //setup_default_uart();
    stdio_init_all();

    // todo get free sm
    PIO pio = pio0;
    uint offset = pio_add_program(pio, &blink_program);
    printf("Loaded program at %d\n", offset);

    gpio_init(0);
    gpio_set_dir(0, GPIO_IN);
    gpio_init(1);
    gpio_set_dir(1, GPIO_OUT);
    gpio_init(2);
    gpio_set_dir(2, GPIO_OUT);

    pio_gpio_init(pio, 0);
    pio_gpio_init(pio, 1);
    pio_gpio_init(pio, 2);
    pio_sm_set_consecutive_pindirs(pio, 1, 1, 2, true);
    pio_sm_set_consecutive_pindirs(pio, 1, 0, 1, false);
    pio_sm_config c = blink_program_get_default_config(offset);
    sm_config_set_in_pins(&c, 0); 
    sm_config_set_out_pins(&c, 1, 2);
    float divider = 2;
    sm_config_set_clkdiv(&c, divider);
    sm_config_set_set_pins(&c, 0, 3);

    pio_sm_init(pio, 1, offset, &c);
    
    setup_dma(pio, 1);

    pio_sm_set_enabled(pio, 1, true);
    

    for(;;) {
        if (bufferReady) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                //if (processingBuffer[i] > 0)
                printf("%08x ", processingBuffer[i]);
            }
            bufferReady = false;
        }

        //uint32_t data = pio_sm_get(pio, 1);
        //printf("%08x ", data);
        //fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, stdout);
        //if (data > 0)
        //    printf("%d", data);
    }
}

So to my problem. DMA seem to work, I get batches of data transferred and I can print the data to serial port (where I increased baud to 115200 to handle the rate). But the problem is that most data is 00000000 and I cannot understand why. If I print all data that is > 0x0 then I will get a more consistent stream but I don't know if it makes sense.
This is how it looks when I only print values > 0x0:
5e950000 1e950000 9e950000 5e950000 ee950000 6e950000 2e950000 2e950000 ae950000 6e950000 ae950000 ae950000 6e950000 1e950000 ee950000 ee950000 6e950000 ae950000 ee950000 1e950000 9e950000 6e950000 ae950000 ae950000 ae950000 ae950000 6e950000 ae950000 6e950000 1e950000 9e950000 9e950000 9e950000 ee950000 6e950000 ce950000  

In a quiet room what would I expect to see here?
Why am I getting so many 00000000 and why is the data I get so weird if I filter away the zeroes?
(This is a follow up to my previous question)
Datasheet SPH0645LM4H-B
EDIT: after correcting the timing problem I get a steady pace of data, but is it correct from a MEMS microphone? How can I know?
3e120600, 3e920000, 3e9a0200, 3e1a0300, 3e1a0100, 3eea0100, 3e6a0500, 3eaa0500, 3e0a0700, 3ef20700, 3ef20100, 3e720600, 3eb20100, 3e720400, 3eaa0000, 3e2a0100, 3e2a0500, 3eaa0700, 3eaa0500, 3eaa0600, 3e8a0200, 3e8a0200, 3e8a0600, 3e4a0400, 3e4a0400, 3e8a0700, 3eb20400, 3e320100, 3eb20400, 3eb20600, 3e320100, 3ed20500, 3ed20000, 3e320400, 3eb20200, 3e720600, 3ef20000, 3ef20100, 3ef20500, 3efa0300, 3efa0300, 3efa0600, 3e7a0500, 3eba0700, 3e7a0000, 3e320500, 3e320200, 3eb20200, 3eb20200, 3e320300, 3e320500, 3ed20300, 3ed20000, 3e920700, 3e520500, 3e520600, 3e920600, 3e520300, 3e320500, 3eb20000, 3eb20600, 3e720500, 3ef20100, 3efa0400, 3efa0500, 3e060400, 3e860100, 3e460000, 3e860600, 3e4a0400, 3e4a0000, 3e4a0600, 3e8a0600, 3e0a0600, 3e0a0100, 3ef20000, 3ef20000, 3e720600, 3e720600, 3ef20000, 3e720400, 3ee20500, 3ee20700, 3e120200, 3e120700, 3e920500, 3ed20200, 3eaa0700, 3e6a0100, 3e6a0500, 3eea0000, 3e1a0400, 3e1a0100, 3eca0500, 3eca0300, 3eca0100, 3e4a0300, 3eca0200, 3eca0100, 3eaa0100, 3eaa0000, 3eaa0500, 3eaa0100, 3e2a0300, 3eaa0200, 3e720100, 3e720500, 3eb20300, 3eb20100, 3eb20600, 3e320600, 3e0a0300, 3e0a0100, 3e0a0500, 3e0a0200, 3e0a0600, 3ef20700, 3e120100, 3e920600, 3e920200, 3e920400, 3e920400, 3e920500, 3e720600, 3e720600, 3e720100, 3ef20000, 3ef20400, 3ef20400, 3e520500, 3e520400, 3e920300, 3e920300, 3e920200, 3e920000, 3e920300, 3e920600, 3e920600, 3e920400, 3e120300, 3e920400, 3ef20200, 3ef20400, 3ef20100, 3ef20200, 3e720300, 3e720500, 3e720100, 3ef20000, 3e720700, 3ef20100, 3e0a0100, 3e4a0600, 3eca0600, 3e2a0000, 3eca0700, 3e2a0200, 3eaa0200, 3eca0500, 3e2a0100, 3e6a0000, 3e6a0100, 3e6a0600, 3e6a0100, 3eea0200, 3eea0400, 3eaa0300, 3eaa0100, 3eaa0300, 3e6a0000, 3e320200, 3ed20700, 3ed20100, 3ed20600, 3ed20200, 3e520600, 3e320400, 3e320100, 3e320700, 3e320300, 3e320700, 3e320700, 3e0a0500, 3e0a0700, 3e0a0500, 3e0a0300, 3e8a0400, 3e0a0300, 3eca0600, 3eca0000, 3e4a0200, 3e8a0600, 3e8a0000, 3e8a0000, 3ef20300, 3ef20500, 3ef20500, 3ef20000, 3ef20200, 3ef20600, 3e0a0300, 3e0a0600, 3e0a0600, 3e0a0400, 3e0a0100, 3e8a0200, 3e520300, 3ed20000, 3e320400, 3ed20700, 3e320600, 3e320200, 3eb20600, 3e720400, 3e720400, 3eb20700, 3e720600, 3ef20000, 3eaa0700, 3e6a0300, 3eea0100, 3eea0000, 3e6a0200, 3eaa0100, 3e320700, 3e320400, 3eb20100, 3e720400, 3e720600, 3e720200, 3e720500, 3ef20300, 3e0a0400, 3ef20700, 3ef20100, 3ef20100, 3e8a0500, 3e8a0100, 3e8a0000, 3e0a0000, 3e720500, 3e720100, 3e720600, 3eb20500, 3eb20700, 3eb20400, 3e320500, 3eb20400, 3e4a0300, 3e8a0100, 3e8a0400, 3e8a0400, 3e4a0600, 3e4a0600, 3e4a0100, 3e4a0400, 3e4a0600, 3e4a0600, 3e4a0100, 3eca0300, 3e2a0500, 3e720700, 3e720500, 3e720300, 3e0a0400, 3e0a0600, 3ef20000, 3e2a0500, 3eca0700, 3eca0700, 3eca0700, 3eca0700, 3e2a0000, 3e0a0300, 3e8a0200, 3e4a0000, 3e4a0000, 3e8a0200, 3e8a0400, 3e720000, 3eb20300, 3e720200, 3e720100, 3e720400, 3e720700, 3e8a0300, 3e4a0400, 3e8a0000, 3e0a0200, 3ef20300, 3ef20600, 3e720300, 3e720200, 3eb20500, 3eb20300, 3eb20000, 3eb20600, 3e720300, 3e720600, 3e720600, 3ef20200, 3e0a0000, 3ef20700, 3eaa0200, 3eaa0000, 3eaa0500, 3eaa0300, 3eaa0300, 3eaa0700, 3eca0200, 3eca0000, 3e4a0500, 3e4a0100, 3e4a0100, 3e4a0400, 3ef20200, 3e720700, 3e720500, 3e720500, 3ef20200, 3ef20500, 3e2a0300, 3eca0500, 3eca0200, 3eca0100, 3e4a0500, 3e4a0000, 3e8a0700, 3eca0000, 3e4a0200, 3e4a0000, 3e4a0400, 3e8a0100, 3ed20700, 3ed20700, 3e320300, 3eb20600, 3eb20100, 3eb20700, 3ef20200, 3ef20000, 3ef20200, 3ef20200, 3e720300, 3e720100, 3e4a0500, 3e8a0100, 3e8a0600, 3e0a0700, 3ef20700, 3e0a0400, 3ef20600, 3e720300, 3eb20400, 3eb20500, 3e720600, 3e720400, 3e9a0000, 3e1a0100, 3e1a0200, 3e1a0600, 3e1a0400, 3e1a0400, 3eaa0400, 3e2a0400, 3eca0400, 3e4a0400, 3e4a0000, 3e8a0100, 3e4a0700, 3eca0000, 3eca0600, 3eca0000, 3eca0000, 3e4a0700, 3ef20400, 3ef20600, 3e0a0000, 3ef20600, 3eb20700, 3e720400, 3e520700, 3e920500, 3e920700, 3ed20000, 3ed20600, 3e520100, 3e520700, 3e520000, 3e520200, 3ed20600, 3e320400, 3e520300, 3eca0000, 3e2a0100, 3e4a0500, 3e8a0600, 3e4a0600, 3e8a0400, 3e8a0600, 3eca0000, 3e8a0400, 3ef20000, 3e0a0200, 3eca0700, 3eca0200, 3e720300, 3e720300, 3e720200, 3e720200, 3e720100, 3e720000, 3e720500, 3e320300, 3ed20600, 3e520100, 3ed20700, 3e520400, 3eb20700, 3eb20200, 3e720400, 3eb20200, 3e0a0300, 3ef20200, 3eca0300, 3e6a0500, 3eca0200, 3eca0000, 3eaa0200, 3e8a0100, 3ef20700, 3e720300, 3e720300, 3ef20300, 3ef20700, 3e720700, 3ef20300, 3ef20300, 3e720700, 3eb20000, 3ef20300, 3e8a0200, 3ed20500, 3e320700, 3e720700, 3ef20000, 3e320400, 3e520200, 3e920100, 3e920400, 3e120600, 3e320000, 3eb20300, 3ed20200, 3ef20600, 3e0a0200, 3e0a0600, 3e0a0000, 3e8a0500, 3e2a0200, 3e0a0300, 3e4a0300, 3e4a0100, 3e4a0400, 3e8a0100, 3e0a0300, 3e2a0600, 3e6a0200, 3e2a0500, 3eca0200, 3eca0700, 3eaa0500, 3eaa0500, 3eca0000, 3eca0500, 3eaa0500, 3eaa0200, 3e2a0100, 3ef20700, 3e0a0000, 3eca0400, 3e4a0100, 3e8a0100, 3e8a0400, 3e2a0400, 3eca0200, 3e8a0700, 3eca0200, 3eca0400, 3e4a0500, 3e120100, 3e920700, 3e920300, 3e520600, 3ed20700, 3e320000, 3e0a0100, 3e0a0000, 3e8a0000, 3e8a0000, 3e8a0200, 3e8a0400, 3e8a0000, 3e0a0400, 3ef20700, 3ef20300, 3ef20200, 3e0a0000, 3e0a0400, 3e0a0700, 3e8a0000, 3e0a0700, 3e8a0200, 3e4a0100, 3ef20200, 3e720100, 3ef20400, 3ef20200, 3ef20000, 3ef20600, 3e320200, 3e320300, 3eb20500, 3e0a0000, 3ef20200, 3e720600, 3e8a0000, 3e8a0500, 3e8a0000, 3e720600, 3eb20700, 3ef20400, 3e0a0500, 3ef20500, 3e0a0400, 3e0a0500, 3e0a0000, 3eb20700, 3eca0400, 3eca0200, 3eca0000, 3e4a0500, 3e4a0100, 3eca0100, 3e2a0300, 3eaa0600, 3e2a0700, 3eca0400, 3eca0300, 3eaa0700, 3eaa0700, 3e220100, 3e220700, 3e620500, 3ee20000, 3ee20300, 3ee20600, 3e120400, 3ee20500, 3e120000, 3ee20300, 3e120700, 3e120000, 3e2a0500, 3eaa0400, 3e4a0200, 3e0a0600, 3eca0300, 3eaa0400, 3ef20100, 3e0a0200, 3ef20300, 


Please link the data sheet of the microphone.

Did so now @Andyaka, I also added an image from logic analyser

So, is the rogue 00000000 data not observable coming from your microphone?

@Andyaka exactly I cannot see 00000000 in the logic analyser, I only see good looking numbers constantly, but received from the PIO I see around 95%+ is 00000000 (have'nt calculated just an estimate)

Try adding a bit of code that overwrites the microphone value with (say) 10101010 and see what happens.

Thanks for the idea @Andyaka, it did however turn out that there was a 1 bit delay missing from the frame sync, after correcting this I get no empty values... After correcting this I also get other values, pasting them above

Plot it in a time/amplitude graph <-- use excel
